# JArray size reduced to 1000 forcefully

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using `Newtonsoft` `JArray` to handle json response but seems `JArray.count()` limited to 1000 always. I loss the rest of the records. Is there any limitation like this or am I missing something? 

Below is the snippet

```
//here rsults is the json response
var obj = JObject.Parse(results);  //this has 6267 in total
var records = (JArray)obj["records"];  //this has 6267 in total

for (int i = 0; i < records.Count(); i++)     //this always limited to 1000
{
   //more code
}
```

Comment: Any way you could provide a short example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Is there not perhaps code inside the for loop which breaks out at 1000?

Comment: Post executable repro code. That will make the problem obvious and you'll be able to answer the question yourself.